# How to group multiple cells with the same values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016

I am trying to group multiple cells in Excel to give me an end value of the total of times those three cells exist, for example, if the Country is "UK", the Method is "Method1" and Weight is "400", instead of that appearing 2 times as it does in the table below, I would like to merge it so it is there only once, but the Amount column has a value of "2" to represent how many times it is in the Sheet.   The data I am using has thousands of different and varying values.  I am using Microsoft Excel 2016.

Thank you.

```
Current Sheet:

Country   Method   Weight   Amount

USA       Method7   200       x
UK        Method1   400       x
UK        Method1   400       x
FRANCE    Method55  3994      x


Desired Sheet:

Country   Method   Weight   Amount

USA       Method7   200       1
UK        Method1   400       2
FRANCE    Method55  3994      1
```

Comment: You can use COUNTIFS to count how many times those conditions *for example, if the Country is "UK", the Method is "Method1" and Weight is "400"* appear. Also, you could resume your data using PivotTables, and sum/count the value of AMOUNT. A Pivot Table would return exactly what you want as *Desired Sheet*

Answer (score 2):

This is how my original data looks like:

[image]

And I can resume it as you need using [Pivot Tables](https://exceljet.net/things-to-know-about-excel-pivot-tables)

[image]

> Make sure you set the Pivot Table Value Property as **count** when
>   using the field *Amount*

Just in case it may help, I'm attaching how I set up this Pivot Table to make the operations you need (please, note my Excel is in Spanish, but position of each field must be the same, and the operation in *Values* section affecting field *Amount* must be **COUNT**)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As there is a direct link between country, method and weight, you can use subtotals for that (menu "Data", chapter "Outline", feature "Subtotals"). You configure it as:

```
At each change in : "Country"
Use function      : "Count"
Add subtotal to:
  Country (No)
  Method  (No)
  Weigth  (No)
  Amount  (Yes)
Replace current subtotals (Yes)
Page break between groups (No)
Summary below data        (Yes)
```

Your result will look as follows:

[image]

By clicking on the numbers 1, 2 or 3 in the left margin, you'll be able to view/hide subtotals for that country.

Comment: That works for counting how many times the Country appears, but I am trying to make it so it counts how many times the Country, Method, and Weight all appear as a group of 3, e.g. if UK, Method1, 400 appear twice, that's 2, if UK, Method3, 400 appears 4 times, that's 4.